# php dirname оставить последнюю папку

Tags: php, path

```
dirname(__FILE__, 1)
```

функция **dirname** выдает мне такую строку

```
/home/admin/web/site.com/public_html/pages/my_folder
```

как мне получить только

```
pages/my_folder
```

или

```
my_folder
```

Comment: найти позицию нужного слеша с конца и взять всё после него? или разбить строку по слешам, взять нужное число элементов массива с конца и склеить через слеш? что вы уже пробовали сделать и что не получилось?

Comment: не как ответ, а просто на заметку, это `dirname(__FILE__, 1)` тоже самое что это `dirname(__FILE__)` и тоже самое что это `__DIR__`. можно не городить столько лишнего.

Comment: @Lexx918 лучше найти позицию нужного слеша с конца и взять всё после него

Comment: ну так найдите https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.strrpos.php а потом возьмите https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.substr.php

Comment: @Lexx918 не важно что за функция , суть получить текущую папку файла в котором эта функция

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Например так:

```
echo basename(dirname(__FILE__)); //my_folder
```

Или просто использовать:

```
echo basename(__DIR__); //my_folder
```

Answer (score 0):

Если нужно найти всё, что находится после последнего слеша, то оптимальным будет такой вариант:

```
$pos = strrpos(__DIR__, DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
$dir = '';

if ($pos !== false) {
    $dir = substr(__DIR__, ++$pos);
}

// После последнего слеша
echo $dir;
```

---

Если нужно искать названия папок от последнего и далее последовательно вверх по директории, то можно так:

```
$dirs = explode(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, __DIR__);

// После последнего слеша
echo end($dirs);
// После предпоследнего слеша
echo prev($dirs);
// После пред-предпоследнего слеша
echo prev($dirs);
// И т.д.
```

P.S.:Вариантов на самом деле множество.

Answer (score 0):

```
$a = strrpos(__DIR__, DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
$dir = '';
if ($a!==false) $dir=substr(__DIR__,++$a);
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 0):

```
$dirname = "/home/admin/web/site.com/public_html/pages/my_folder";
$chunk = explode(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $dirname);

echo implode(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, array_slice($chunk, -2)); // pages/my_folder
echo implode(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, array_slice($chunk, -1)); // my_folder
```