# Обрезать сроку до символа PHP

Tags: php, строки

Есть строка:

```
http://site.com/dashboard
```

Задача:

Обрезать весь текст перед последним слешем и вместе с последним слешем, то-есть на выходе должны получить только `dashboard`

Прошу помощи в реализации!

Comment: Вот тут про explode: https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.explode.php

После вызвать последний элемент массива функцией `end`

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [php dirname оставить последнюю папку](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1006564/php-dirname-%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%bd%d1%8e%d1%8e-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%ba%d1%83)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
basename('http://site.com/dashboard'); // echo = dashboard
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$str = 'http://site.com/dashboard';

$result = substr($str, strrpos($str, '/') + 1, strlen($str));

echo $result;
```